# Cannot resolve toPromise in an angular webservice

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs

I am trying to create a very simple angular service:

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export class Webservice {

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  getMessages() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:63962/api/someshittyendpoint').toPromise();
  }
}
```

Whatever I do, I get the following `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'`.

I have installed rxjs-compat and verified that the module actually is on the path. I don't understand what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Angular and RxJS versions you use?

Comment: The latest, but @martin had the answer.

Comment: I'm so curious if you're doing the .Net / Angular messageboard tutorial, because that's the exact reason I'm here.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky yes, that was the tutorial I was following :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`toPromise` is not an operator. It's a method on the `Observable` class which means you don't have to import it:

See the source code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.11/src/Observable.ts#L332-L354

Comment: Seems I was following an outdated guide for how to consume a webservice. Thanks!