# Module not found ..Cannot resolve module 'rxjs/operators/toPromise with Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am receiving   an error when trying to build my application using angular 6 and have no idea what to do.

Module rxjs not found 
 [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofyvy.png)

```
Module not found ..Cannot resolve module 'rxjs/operators/toPromise
```

what should i do ?

// the contact.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Contact } from './contact';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

    @Injectable()
    export class ContactService {
      private contactsUrl = '/api/contacts';
      constructor (private http: Http) {}
 .......
    }
```

Comment: can you check `package.json` what rxjs version you have installed?

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.0.0",

Comment: toPromise is not a operator anymore you should be directly able to access as Observable method, you can simply remove the import it should work

Comment: @AbineshDevadas is right! This is the answer to the question. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve toPromise in an angular webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544149/cannot-resolve-topromise-in-an-angular-webservice)

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the import statement. It should work without that. Below code works.

```
new Observable().toPromise();
```

From rxjs 5.5, "toPromise: now exists as a permanent method on Observable"

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

From rxjs 6 onwards toPromise is not an operator, it is part of observable object, you should be able to access directly without any imports